# MVC Styling the tabs

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Here are the tabs in the master page:

```
<nav>
     <ul id="menu">
         <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
         <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the css:

```
ul#menu li.selected a {
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    color: #000;
}
```

But no matter what I do to background-color, it always remains the same. How to change the background color and the height of the selected tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:active` selector doesn't style the link that corresponds with the current page, but it styles the link on which is the user is currently clicking.

The `:active` selector is really similar to the `:hover` selector, which styles the link when the user is hovering over it. They are both selectors which are responding to mouse actions.

Here is a sample which shows the behavior rather obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/NuExP/

Edit after you modified the question:

Like @o.v. said, there is no selector for the current active page, so his solution to add a class to the link to indicate that it is the current active page is correct.

Comment: @JessevanAssen: +1 for quick pointers for OP, although imo a comparison with `:hover` could be seen as confusing

Comment: I added it because both selectors are responding to mouse actions, but now I see how it could be confusing. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to change the styling of a tab that is currently selected? If so, you should be adding a css class like `.current` server-side to one of the tabs (also, you may need to style li element rather than the link inside it - but it all depends on the current css structure)

`:active` pseudo-class is used for [a different purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3aactive), you could see it applied when you, for instance, click and hold on the anchor.

Comment: @Scree: there is currently no native logic for an anchor pseudoclass to have its src matched against the current document location. You will end up having to add a class to the "current" tab on the server-side (preferable) or on the client-side with javascript (generally frowned upon)